# SQL/Oracle: Is it possible to have a group function in a check constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

My Tables are:

```
 CREATE TABLE member
             (
                          svn      INTEGER,
                          campid   INTEGER,
                          tentname VARCHAR(4),
                          CONSTRAINT member_fk_svn FOREIGN KEY (svn) REFERENCES people,
                          CONSTRAINT member_fk_campid FOREIGN KEY (campid) REFERENCES camp ON
             DELETE CASCADE,
                    CONSTRAINT member_pk PRIMARY KEY (svn, campid),
                    CONSTRAINT member_fk_tentname FOREIGN KEY (tentname) REFERENCES tent,
                    CONSTRAINT check_teilnehmer_zelt CHECK (Count(zeltname) over (PARTITION BY (zeltname
             AND    lagerid)) )<= zelt.schlafplaetze
             );
```

With the last constraint, I want to check that there are not more members assigned to a tent than the capacity of it.

Thank you in advances for your help

Comment: Sounds like the sort of thing you'd do with a trigger

Comment: I think you can do this with a user-defined function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you elaborate on that? I don't see how.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've poked around the Oracle docs and it does not appear that existing versions allow a CHECK against a UDF.

Comment: @MatBailie . . . Interesting.  Many other databases do allow that, although I don't think I have ever used that functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would require a SQL **assertion**, which is not currently supported by Oracle (or indeed any DBMS).  However, Oracle are [considering adding support for these in the future](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13028) (please upvote that idea!)

**Solution using a Materialized View**

Currently you may be able to implement this constraint using a materialized view (MV) with a check constraint - something [I blogged about many years ago](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2004/10/enforcing-complex-constraints-in.html).  In your case the materialized view query would be something like:

```
select t.tent_id
  from tents t, members m
 where m.tent_id = t.tent_id
 group by t.tent_id
 having sum(m.num_members) > t.capacity;
```

The check constraint could be:

```
check (t.tent_id is null)
```

The check constraint would be violated for any row returned by the materialized view, so ensures that the MV is always empty i.e. no tents exist that are over capacity.

Notes:

1. I deliberately did not use ANSI join syntax, since MVs don't tend to like it (the same join may be permitted in old syntax but not permitted in ANSI syntax). Of course feel free to try ANSI first.
2. I haven't confirmed that this particular query is permitted in an MV with REFRESH COMPLETE ON COMMIT.  The rules on what can and cannot be used vary from version to version of Oracle.
3. Watch out for the performance impact of maintaining the MV.

**Alternative solution using a trigger**

Another way would be to add a column `total_members` to the `tents` table, and use a trigger on `members` to maintain that e.g.

```
create trigger members_trg
  after insert or delete or update of num_members on members
  for each row
  declare
    l_total_members tents.total_members%type;
  begin
    select total_members
      into l_total_members
      from tents
     where tent_id = nvl(:new.tent_id,:old.tent_id)
       for update of total_members;

    if inserting then
      l_total_members := l_total_members + :new.num_members;
    elsif deleting then
      l_total_members := l_total_members - :old.num_members;
    elsif updating then
      l_total_members := l_total_members - :old.num_members + :new.num_members;
    end if;

    update tents
       set total_members = l_total_members 
     where tent_id = nvl(:new.tent_id,:old.tent_id);
  end;
```

Then just add the check constraint:

```
alter table tents add constraint tents_chk
  check (total_members <= capacity);
```

By maintaining the total in the `tents` table, this solution serializes transactions and thus avoids the data corruption you will get with other trigger-based solutions in multi-user environments.

Comment: I thought that some RDBMS allow check constraints to check against user defined functions, does Oracle not allow that?

Comment: Oracle definitely doesn't, I don't know about other RDBMSs.

Comment: I just asked because of the `(or indeed any DBMS)` statement.  MS SQL Server, for example, does.

Comment: Do you mean that MS SQL Server supports **create assertion**?  Because that is what I said it did not support. I could be wrong, but that is my understanding.

Comment: Syntactically, no, functionally yes.  You can check against a user defined scalar function, and that function can query against other rows, other tables, etc.

Comment: Not supported by *any* DBMS? Well, perhaps my memories are wrong, but it seems to me that Back In The Day (tm) Rdb (originally a DEC product, later acquired by Oracle, and still available from Oracle for the VMS platform) allowed check constraints of the form `CHECK(SOME_COLUMN IS NULL OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_ON_OTHER_TABLE = SOME_COLUMN)`.

Comment: This trigger decision can violate data consistency. Check the simple scenario: 1) first session inserts into members 2) second session inserts into members 3) first session commits 4) second session commits. At least you should add FOR UPDATE clause into the first SELECT statement. As well this trigger does not handle, say, updating of tent_id column of the members table.

Comment: @SanderstheSoftwarer Correct - I have added the missing `for update` now.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. From the documentation:

> The search condition must always return the same value if applied to
>   the same values. Thus, it cannot contain any of the following:
>
> ```
> * Dynamic parameters (?)
> * Date/Time Functions (CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
> * Subqueries
> * User Functions (such as USER, SESSION_USER, CURRENT_USER)
> ```